How to correct and interpret my Socure consumer report?
I recently received my consumer report from Socure here: https://www.socure.com/datarights. I had two questions, which I also just posed to Socure at their privacy support email address.

How can I correct incorrect information that they have about me? I don't see on the website how to do that. However, they seem to be set up to comply with the CCPA and similar laws.
Do you have any advice on how to interpret the results? A lot of it seems self-explanatory. However, they gave me my report in a number of JSON files with names = 0, 1, 2 etc; each file contains records which are not always clearly labeled.

I'm guessing that maybe none of you know, but I would love to hear just any advice you have on how to approach the problem. I can break this into 2 questions if you want.
This report was recently used to deny my bank account application. Not super-relevant but I figured you might ask.

I'm not familiar with their API, so can't help you with the technical part.
For CCPA compliance, you can refer to the California Attorney General. If they're not providing you the information required in a way that you can consume it then it may be argued that they're not compliant.
For the use of that information in order to deny you credit or financial services you can ref to the Consumer Financial Protection Bureau. There are certain limitations and requirements under the Fair Credit Reporting Act that they'd need to comply with.

Thanks! That does make sense. Most of their website is talking about ID verification but some of it goes beyond that. So maybe FCRA comes into play? I'm not sure, not a lawyer. I'll look into it Thanks for the info!
